# Geo question about lengths

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I have a question from a maths paper.

Let $ABC$ be an isosceles triangle with base $BC$ and Angle $BAC$ = 100. The bisector of Angle $ABC$ intersects
$AC$ in $P$ . Show that $BC$ = $AP$ +$PB$.

Could I have some help solving this?
Thanks

Comment: Please also tell us what have you tried so far so we can omit a part of solution and give help in the exact place you're stuck, and what methods are allowed to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm in 11th grade and know somewhat advanced maths for my grade. I don't really know how or where to start.

Comment: @sargon129 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I'm telling you, I'm stuck as to where to begin

Comment: I'm better at the angle side of geo, not lengths

Comment: @sargon129 It's impossible that you did not try something. Show it and you'll get a nice solution immediately.

Comment: sigh, I just asked to try and get an answer but...

Comment: @sargon129 If you don't make so, this topic would be deleted. But I don't want that my solution would be deleted.

Comment: pls, i just want an answer

Comment: you are rude man

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if coordiate method is allowed, let $A(0,\cos(50^\circ)), C(\sin(50^\circ),0), B(-\sin(50^\circ),0)$.
Bissector of $\angle ABC$ intersects $OA$ in $(0,\tan(20^\circ)\sin(50^\circ))$ so let's say $BP$ is $\{uB+(1-u)(0,\tan(20^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)),u\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $AC$ is $\{vA+(1-v)C,v\in\mathbb{R}\}$, 
$$P=AC\cap BP:u(-\sin(50^\circ),0)+(1-u)(0,\tan(20^\circ)\sin(50^\circ))=
v(0,\cos(50^\circ))+(1-v)(\sin(50^\circ),0)
$$
$$\begin{cases}
x: -u\sin(50^\circ)=(1-v)\sin(50^\circ),\\
y: (1-u)\tan(20^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)=v\cos(50^\circ)
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
u=v-1,\\
(1-(v-1))\tan(20^\circ)\cos(40^\circ)=v\sin(40^\circ)
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
u=v-1,\\
(2-v)=2v\cot(20^\circ)\tan(40^\circ)
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
u=v-1,\\
2=v(2\cot(20^\circ)\tan(40^\circ)+1)
\end{cases}$$
$|AP|=|P-A|=|vA+(1-v)C-A|=|1-v|\cdot|A-C|=|1-v|$,
$|BP|=|P-B|=
|(u-1)B+(1-u)(0,\tan(20^\circ)\sin(50^\circ))|=
|1-u|\cdot|(0,\tan(20^\circ)\sin(50^\circ))-B|=
|1-u|\sqrt{\sin^2(50^\circ)+\tan^2(20^\circ)\sin^2(50^\circ)}$
We need to show that $|AP|+|BP|=2\sin(50^\circ)$ from here (we can [wolframalpha this thing, see "x" result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B-u*sin%2850%2F180*pi%29%3D%281-v%29*sin%2850%2F180*pi%29%2C+%281-u%29*tan%2820%2F180*pi%29*sin%2850%2F180*pi%29%3Dv*cos%2850%2F180*pi%29%2C+abs%281-u%29*sqrt%28%281%2Btan%5E2%2820%2F180*pi%29%29*sin%5E2%2850%2F180*pi%29%29%2Babs%281-v%29%3Dx%7D)).

Maybe you could try (another way) some auxilary constructions like some line symmetries or so.
Or maybe recall any properties of angles $40^\circ$, $20^\circ$, $20^\circ$.
Or use the sine rule to prove $\frac{PA}{PC}=\frac{BA}{BC}$, then find $PA$ from there and use a sine or cosine rule on $\Delta PAB$ find $PB$.

Comment: $\sin 10°+\sin 50°=\sin 70°$ maybe?  To derive: Use the appropriate sum-product relation to render $\sin 10°+\sin 50°=2\cos 20°\sin 30°$ and simplify from there.

Comment: Edited the answer, now $|AP|+|BP|$ fits $2\sin(50^\circ)$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Construct isosceles triangle BDC and the congruent triangles ABP $\approx$ QBP. Then, the triangles PDC and PQC are congruent, which leads to PD + PQ = AP. Then,

$$BC = BD = BP + PD = BP + AP$$

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the Pic.[image]